# Converting Panda Dataframe 24 hour to 12 hour in Python3

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, group-by, python-datetime

I have data from two different sources, where one uses a 12 hour time and another that uses 24 hour time. I would like to convert the 24 hour time to 12 hour time, as I have more data in this format. Since my program will merge all the data into one CSV file and then plot the data by weeks, I need the time format to be the same. Since the data is read in as a Panda dataframe, I thought if I converted the column to datetime that I could convert the 24 hour to 12 hour. Since I can perform this translation in Excel, there has to be a way in Python3 that I am just not understanding.

I have tried the following command and many variations of this without any luck:
df["FORMATTED DATE_TIME--yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss a"] = pd.to_datetime(df["FORMATTED DATE_TIME--yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss a"], format="%Y-%m-%d %I:%M:%S %p").

No matter what I try, I keep getting the following error:
ValueError: time data "2023-07-29 12:32:00" doesn't match format "%Y-%m-%d %I:%M:%S %p", at position 0. You might want to try:
- passing `format` if your strings have a consistent format;
- passing `format='ISO8601'` if your strings are all ISO8601 but not necessarily in exactly the same format;
- passing `format='mixed'`, and the format will be inferred for each element individually. You might want to use `dayfirst` alongside this.

I also tried:
d=df[1]["FORMATTED DATE_TIME--yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss a"].datetime.strptime

And get the following error:
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'datetime'

I would be happy to share my code and data files but I do not see where to post files. I am new to this community and this is my first post. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: are you able to add a few rows of data that the code breaks on for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) ?

Comment: 2023-09-02 14:22:00,77.5,66.9,58.2,30.15,268,29.53,2.5,77.4,61.6,1877,2.4,0.5,78,78,77.4
2023-09-02 14:24:00,77.7,66.6,56.8,30.15,273,29.53,0.0,77.5,61.2,1891,0.0,0.0,286,287,77.5
2023-09-02 14:26:00,77.3,66.2,56.4,30.14,276,29.52,0.8,76.8,60.6,1867,0.8,-0.1,260,260,77.2

Comment: I posted three rows of data but omitted the header as the format looked bad. Hopefully this is helpful. If there is a way to post files, I would be happy to post a snippet of the data with the header but I do not see where I can post files.

Comment: Was able to figure this out, needed to add the following two lines of code:         df.iloc[:,0] = df.iloc[:,0].apply(pd.to_datetime, format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
df.iloc[:,0] = df.iloc[:,0].apply(pd.to_datetime, format = '%Y-%m-%d %I:%M:%S %p')

Answer (score 0):

Needed to add these two lines of code to change from 24hr to 12hr format:

```py
df.iloc[:,0] = df.iloc[:,0].apply(pd.to_datetime, format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
df.iloc[:,0] = df.iloc[:,0].apply(pd.to_datetime, format = '%Y-%m-%d %I:%M:%S %p')
```